# Dropbox folder does not seem to open

Tags: dropbox

How can I access a folder someone sent me? As soon as I click on the Sharing link, it directs me to a new page and the folder says "this folder is empty". Is there fault or is it just busy downloading?

Comment: Are you looking on your own computer or the web interface?

Comment: my own computer - i am still very new to this app, downloaded it a few minutes ago =)

Comment: It's very likely that the sync just hasn't completed. You've installed the app, yes? Have you looked in the folder on the Dropbox website?

Comment: Ah man, isn't there a way to see how long it's still going to take? Otherwise I have to leave my computer on for the night or wait until it's done. I looked in the folder - only the sample album is visible.

Answer (score 1):

When you look on the web and the folder is full it will just take some time to get to your computer. If you look on the web and it is empty then it is just empty.